# В чем отличие process.argv от rl.on( 'line', {})

Tags: node.js

Только начинаю изучать Node js и не могу понять в каких случаях использовать process.argv, а в каких rl.on('line', {}) ?

Comment: Во всём. `process.argv` это то что вы написали в командной строке когда запускали скрипт, а `rl.on...` это то что скрипт будет получать со стандартного входа (клавиатуры) в процессе работы программы.

Comment: спасибо, поняла